# Upload audio clip realtime while its recording?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

How to upload audio clip realtime to a server while its recording? Basically my requirement is upload an audio clip as chucks/packets while its recording.
I already did the recording part with using IQAudioRecorderController https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQAudioRecorderController. It records the audio and save to TemporaryDirectory.

I wanted to know how to upload realtime without saving the audio clip.

This is the recording part

```
//Unique recording URL


NSString *fileName = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
_recordingFilePath = [NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.m4a",fileName]];


// Initiate and prepare the recorder

_audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:_recordingFilePath] settings:recordSetting error:nil];
_audioRecorder.delegate = self;
_audioRecorder.meteringEnabled = YES;


// Recording start
- (void)recordingButtonAction:(UIBarButtonItem *)item
{
 if (_isRecording == NO)
  {
    _isRecording = YES;

    //UI Update
    {
        [self showNavigationButton:NO];
        _recordButton.tintColor = _recordingTintColor;
        _playButton.enabled = NO;
        _trashButton.enabled = NO;
    }

    /*
     Create the recorder
     */
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:_recordingFilePath])
    {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:_recordingFilePath error:nil];
    }

    _oldSessionCategory = [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] category];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord error:nil];
    [_audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    [_audioRecorder record];
}
else
{
    _isRecording = NO;

    //UI Update
    {
        [self showNavigationButton:YES];
        _recordButton.tintColor = _normalTintColor;
        _playButton.enabled = YES;
        _trashButton.enabled = YES;
    }

    [_audioRecorder stop];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:_oldSessionCategory error:nil];
}
}  

// Recording done

-(void)doneAction:(UIBarButtonItem*)item
{
  if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(audioRecorderController:didFinishWithAudioAtPath:)])
  {
      IQAudioRecorderController *controller = (IQAudioRecorderController*)[self navigationController];
      [self.delegate audioRecorderController:controller didFinishWithAudioAtPath:_recordingFilePath];
  }

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are various ways of solving this, one way is to create your own AudioGraph. The AudioGraph can grab samples from microphone or from a file. Then you proceed to an output unit, but install a callback to get the sampled frames. These you then push to your network class which then can upload packet by packet.

A good example that shows you how to write these captured packets to disk is [AVCaptureAudioDataOutput](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012880-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2) .

In that example packets are written suing ExtAudioFileWriteAsync. You have to replace this with your own logic for uploading to a server. Note that while you can do that easily, one problem is that this will give you raw audio samples. If you need them as wave file or similar, you may need to wait until recording is finished, since the header of the file needs an information about contained audio samples.

Answer (score -1):

The code you are currently using will work for you if you want to upload recorded file after recording is done as it will give you the final recorded file.

If you want to upload live audio recording to the server then I think you have to go with combination of,

AudioSession for recording stuff

[ffmpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg) for uploading your live audio to server.

You can get good help for recording audio and managing Audio Buffers from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/AVCaptureToAudioUnit/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012880-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

For ffmpeg I think you have to lear a lot. It will be easy to send static/saved audio file to server using ffmpeg but for sending live Audio Buffer to server will be tricky job.

Comment: You don't need `ffmpeg` to upload audio, and you will likely have licensing issues with putting an app built with in on the App Store.

Comment: There might be other options for ffmpeg, but if you concern about licensing then there is no issue submitting a build to App Store because I successfully submitted an app with ffmpeg implementation to App Store, but you have to mention that you are using it in your app for credit purpose.

Comment: ffmpeg is licensed LGPL. The terms of the LGPL are incompatible with the App Store. Basically, you're violating the ffmpeg licensing terms. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/1229

Comment: In any case you do not need ffmpeg to stream audio, Apple has built-in libraries that do it just fine.